# Move in real time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, socket.io, real-time, move

I'm writing a real time game and i don't have any idea how to make a move in real time (like a mmorpg games)

Now my codes only add new character to the window..

Look and plis take me any addvice!!! :(

**Server (Socket.io):**

```
var handler = function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
    });
}

var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var port =  3250;

app.listen(port);
var postacie = [];
var idGenerator = 0;

// socket.io
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var pId = idGenerator++;
    socket.emit("list", postacie);

    var postac = createChar(pId);
    postacie.push(postac);
    io.sockets.emit("join", postac);

    socket.on("disconnect", function()
    {
        var sId = "character" + pId;
        for (var i = 0,n=postacie.length; i < n; ++i) {
            var postac = postacie[i];
            if (postac.id == sId) {
                io.sockets.emit("leave", {id:postac.id});
                postacie.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });

});


function createChar(id)
{
    var postac = {
        src: "http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/1416/2st.gif",
        id: "character" + id
    };
    return postac;
}
```

**Client:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Real tie game</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {

                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3250');

                socket.on("join", function(data)
                {
                    var element = document.createElement('img');
                    element.src = data.src;
                    element.id = data.id;

                    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                    body.appendChild(element);

                });
                socket.on("list", function(data)
                {
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                      var element = document.createElement('img');
                      element.src = data[i].src;
                      element.id = data[i].id;

                      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                      body.appendChild(element);
                    };

                });
                socket.on("leave", function(data)
                {
                    var element = document.getElementById(data.id);
                    if (element)
                        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                });

            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "make a move" mean in this context? Are you talking about animating something on screen, or updating the associated data across the network? (Or both?)

Answer (score 0):

There is two general approaches to sync client with servers state.

**First** of all server should have loop on its side, where it will perform all updates of game objects, move them, change states, etc. This is called `update` and there is `ups` - Updates Per Second. For MMO it can be in between 2-10, based on how much 'close to real-time' you want.

Then every certain period, no more often than `ups` but can be more rare, you need to send state to client, with positions of objects. It can be done for example 5 times a second (every 200 ms). Client will have to interpolate or extrapolate, it is called `dead reckoning`.

**Second** approach would be event based, where server would send events to client, for example `object_1024 moved to x,y`, then client would need to have own loop in order to move object from present location to the new one.

If it is game development related, better to ask here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/